# For loop not working two id plus variable

Tags: javascript

Hi there I am trying to make this for loop

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  sizeNestable();
});

  for (p = 1; p <= 20; p++) { 

$('#nestable'+p+', #nestable'+(p+1)).change(function() {
   sizeNestable();
});




function sizeNestable() {
  var n3 = $('#nestable3').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
  var n4 = $('#nestable4').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 


}
}

</script>
```

So what I need is

```
$('#nestable1, #nestable2').change(function() {
```

and

```
 var n3 = $('#nestable1).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');
```

and then to increase for one ..
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are just incrementing up by one each time, why are you doing `'#nestable'+n'` and `#nestable'+(n+1)`. What is preventing you from just  using one? Aren't you doing double work?

Comment: I need that to be on that way

Comment: I also can't see where the end of your for loop is, nor do I see where you instantiate the `n` variable. So, `n` may not be in the scope of `sizeNestable()`. You may want to consider passing `n` into the `sizeNestable` function.

Comment: What errors are you getting? It is important to post that and not just say "it isn't working". What behavior are you expecting? What behavior are you getting?

Comment: I also notice some syntax errors you should fix first. `'#nestable'+n', #nestable'+(n+1)` is not valid JavaScript you're missing a `+` after `+n` so it should be `'#nestable'+n+', #nestable'+(n+1)`. And `var n4 = $('#nestable2'+(n+1)` is missing a `)` at the end. You should see at least some of those errors in the JavaScript console of your browser..

Comment: Also, ` var n3 = $('#nestable1).find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');` has a syntax error. It should be ` var n3 = $('#nestable1').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');`

Comment: I eddited my code as you can see, I only need to know  this two  var n3 = $('#nestable3').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%'); 
  var n4 = $('#nestable4').find('.dd3-handle').height('100%');  how to put the variable p

Comment: You should add a parameter to your `function sizeNestable(p)` and use that, don't forget to call the function with a valid argument. But I assume there is better solution to your problem, not using so many different IDs, but rather a single CSS class `.nestable` for example. :)

Comment: Which kind of element is "nestable1", "nestable2" ? onChange is something used for input elements (or select, radio buttons, ...).  But there are elements nested inside of these.Would you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. But there are a few errors I see.

function sizeNestable does not belong inside a for-loop.  Instead you should give the function a parameter, you should call that function inside the loop and pass p (or something else) as a parameter.

Your for-loop is not inside a function, yet it contains HTML elements.  This must be avoided.
You should keep away from HTML elements, until document.ready .  It's okay to have HTML inside a function, because a function is only executed when you call it.  Your for-loop is executed as soon as the script is loaded, and the HTML might not be ready yet.

My code contains the pieces of your code, please explain what you are trying to do.  Which kind of HTML elements are you talking about?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    for (var p = 1; p <= 20; p++) { 
      var selector = '#nestable' + p ;
      $(selector).click(function() {
        sizeNestable(this); // inside this kind of function (triggered by an event) 'this' is whatever was triggered (in this case clicked on)
      });
    }
  });

  function sizeNestable(element) {
    $(element).find('.dd3-handle').css('height', '100%'); 
  }

</script>
<style>
.mydiv {
  height: 20px;
}
.dd3-handle {
  height: 3px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
</style>
<div class="mydiv" id="nestable1">Hello <div class="dd3-handle">|||</div> </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="nestable2">World <div class="dd3-handle">|||</div> </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="nestable3">! <div class="dd3-handle">|||</div> </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="nestable4">foo <div class="dd3-handle">|||</div> </div>
<div class="mydiv" id="nestable5">bar <div class="dd3-handle">|||</div> </div>
<hr/>
<p>Click on one of the lines above.  hidden ||| elements will appear</p>
```